Programmatically plotting tables with arrow connections
I need to produce a bunch of figures like the one below.
I am certain that it can be achieve in LaTeX. What I am not sure about is whether is it possible to create a function that, given the entries of the tables and the connections, would produce the figures programmatically.
I have tried the following code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm, align=left},
    arrow/.style={-latex}
]
  % Boxes
  \node[box] (box1) {XXXXX\\xxxxx1\\xxxxx2\\xxxxx3\\xxxxx4};
  \node[box, right=2cm of box1] (box2) {YYYYY\\yyyyy1\\yyyyy2\\yyyyy3\\yyyyy4};
  \node[box, right=2cm of box2] (box3) {ZZZZZ\\zzzzz1\\zzzzz2\\zzzzz3\\zzzzz4\\zzzzz5};
  
  % Arrows
  \draw[arrow] (box2) -- (box1);
  \draw[arrow] (box3) -- (box2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I imagine the wanted function as receiving this input:
{{
table XXXXX,
xxx1
xxx2,
xxx3,
},
{
table YYYYY,
yyy1
yyy2,
yyy3,
},
{
connections:
XXXXX:1 -> YYYYY:2
}}

The number of tables can vary, as well as the number of table entries. In the example above, row 1 of table XXXXX connects to row 2 of table YYYYY, with the arrow orientation given by ->.
Thanks in advance!


Help us yo help you :) Can you please add to your question, the 3 tables you display for instance, some compilable code with the documentclass, etc.

Thanks, @JeT! I have just added the code.

What format is your data in? What stays the same and what varies? What would your ideal function look like? Do you want to use it in a tikzpicture? Or do you want the function to create one?

Thanks, @cfr! I have edited my question accordingly.

You should look for UML packages.

Here is a first sketch which uses {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% The following counter will count the occurrences of the command \Draw
\int_new:N \g__PaulS_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__PaulS_arrow:n #1 { \__PaulS_arrow_aux:w #1 \q_stop }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__PaulS_arrow_aux:w #1 - #2 -> #3 - #4 \q_stop
  { 
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } < { #3 } 
      { \draw [-LaTeX] (#1-#2.5-|#1-2) -- (#3-#4.5-|#3-1) ; }
      { \draw [-LaTeX] (#1-#2.5-|#1-1) -- (#3-#4.5-|#3-2) ; }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \Draw } { m m } 
  {
    \group_begin:
    \int_gincr:N \g__PaulS_int
    % the following counter will count the tables
    \int_zero_new:N \l__PaulS_int
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \int_incr:N \l__PaulS_int
        \begin { NiceTabular } 
          [ 
            t , 
            name = PaulS - \int_use:N \g__PaulS_int - \int_use:N \l__PaulS_int
          ] 
          { c }
        \bfseries 
        \clist_use:nn { ##1 } { \\ }
        % we draw the rules in the current table 
        \CodeAfter
          \begin { tikzpicture }
            \draw (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
            \draw (2-|1) -- (2-|last) ; 
          \end { tikzpicture }
        \end { NiceTabular }
        \hspace { 1cm }
      }
    % now, we draw the arrows
      \begin{tikzpicture} 
        [ 
          remember~picture, 
          overlay , 
          name~prefix = PaulS - \int_use:N \g__PaulS_int -
        ]
      \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } \__PaulS_arrow:n 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \group_end:
  }

% the following lines are not necesssary with recent versions of LaTeX
\cs_set:Nn \int_if_zero:nT { \int_compare:nNnT { #1 } = 0 { #2 } }
\cs_set:Nn \int_if_zero:nTF { \int_compare:nNnT { #1 } = 0 { #2 } { #3 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}

\Draw 
  {
    { table XXXXX, xxx1 xxx2, xxx3 } ,
    { table YYYYY, yyy1 yyy2, yyy3 } , 
    { table ZZZ, zz1 zzz2, zzz4 , zzz5 } 
  }
  { 1-1->2-2 , 2-3->1-3 , 2-1->3-3 }

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because of the use of TikZ nodes with the key remember picture).


Thanks! I have tried you solution, but I am getting the following compilation error:

! Package nicematrix Error: Duplicate name. (nicematrix)                The name 'PaulS-2' is already used and you (nicematrix)                shouldn't use the same environment name twice. (nicematrix)                You can go on, but, maybe, you will have (nicematrix)                incorrect results especially if you use (nicematrix)                'columns-width=auto'. If you don't want to see (nicematrix)                this message again, use the key (nicematrix)                'allow-duplicate-names' in '\NiceMatrixOptions'.

You are right. It was not possible to use my previous command \Draw  several times because. I have modified my answer and, now, it should be possible.

Brilliant solution! Thanks!
